# Python - Extract data from nested dictionary into Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, openpyxl

I have a nested dictionary and I want to do the following:

1. Create excel worksheet based on name of dictionary (Excel sheets called dict1, dict2 etc based on example below)
2. Create headers in the Excel sheet that match the dictionary - so cell A1 = `key1`, cell B1 = `key2`
3. Populate the data that I have in the dictionary into the relevant columns (e.g col A2,A3,A4 etc to have `data1`, `data2`, `data3` (and the same for the rest of the columns)

Input dictionary example:

```
nested_dict = {'dict_1': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3'], 'key3': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']},
'dict_2': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3'], 'key3': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}}
```

Desired output in Excel

```
key1 | key2|key3|
data1| 1   |value1
data2| 2   |value2
data3| 3   |value3
```

I am currently using openpyxl to try to achieve this but not exactly sure how to iterate through the nested dictionary correctly and access create worksheets for each dictionary then repeat for the rest of the data.

```
for k,v in nested_dict.items:
    for sheetName in wb.sheetnames:
        wb.create_sheet(k)
        ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value 
        
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This basically the same as your previous question. It looks like you're not even trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use 'pandas' package

```
import pandas as pd
nested_dict = {'dict_1': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3'], 'key3': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']},
               'dict_2': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3'], 'key3': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}
               }
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
for sheet,data in nested_dict.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet,index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: thank you  - only thing is that its overwriting the existing sheets in my excel file. Is there anyway to keep existing sheets and then add the A. B etc worksheets?

Comment: writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx',mode='a',engine='openpyxl')

Comment: In addition, the 'test.xlsx' file must exist first